# R: calculating approximation error of pi approximation with monte carlo

Tags: r, montecarlo, pi, sample-size

I'm new to computer simulations and R programming as a new module I had to study in college I had some issues understanding the problem asking in an exercise

The code I'm trying with :

```
runs <- 100000
#runif samples from a uniform distribution
xs <- runif(runs,min=-0.5,max=0.5)
ys <- runif(runs,min=-0.5,max=0.5)
in.circle <- xs^2 + ys^2 <= 0.5^2
mc.pi <- (sum(in.circle)/runs)*4
# absdif <- abs(mc.pi - 3.14159265)
# print(absdif)
plot(xs,ys,pch=".",col=ifelse(in.circle,"blue","red"),xlab='',ylab='',asp=1, main=paste("MC Approximation of Pi =",mc.pi))
```

Is the variable "runs" considered as the sample size in the exercise ? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I answered the 1 question I saw in your text... but you start it with "Also...". If you have another question, please try to articulate it more clearly.

Comment: I really don't understand your confusion. You post working code. Your first line you set the sample size to `100000` with `runs <- 100000`. `mc.pi` is the estimate of `pi`. Your `plot()` the diagram. So, it seems like your code works. Can you be more specific about what you're looking for "tips or directions" on? When you say "help me with what is asked", what is asked that isn't already in your code? Please re-read your question and make sure everything you intend to be there is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `runs` variable configures how many samples are drawn, so it is the way you configure the sample size in this code. If you look at the `?runif` help page, the first argument is the number of samples to draw, so your code `runif(runs, ...)` draws `runs` sample points from a uniform distribution.